# Hibernate Hbm2Java generating POJOs with invalid data types

Tags: java, hibernate, pojo, hbm2java

I'm a beginner to Hibernate and have a very little knowledge of its internals. I'm generating POJOs from the xml schema by Hibernate's tool **Hbm2Java**. When I run that tool, it goes through my model (xml schema) and generates the respective POJOs. But when I open the generated file, the members in the POJOs have invalid data types, which doesn't allow me to compile the code.
I have a **Hbm2Ddl** task as well which generates the .sql file for the same model. Hbm2Ddl generates the .sql file as required. What could be possibly wrong?

Here's how the generated .java file looks like.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.*;
@XmlRootElement

public class MyPojo implements java.io.Serializable {

     private integer id;
     private double funds;
     private string name;

     public integer getId() {
        return this.id;
     }
     public void setId(integer id) {
        this.id = id;
     }
     // ---------------- Snipped - Rest of the setters/getters --------------------
}
```

How can I find why this is happenning?

Comment: `integer` & `string`? it must be `Integer` and `String`

Comment: integer & string? it must be int and String

Comment: What is the hibernate version you are using? Probably a bug which was fixed in newer releases. Or else you found a new bug and can report it.

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder: ya that is exactly my problem. Why is it generating invalid data types?

Comment: @shazin: I'm using Hibernate 3.2.5 and it seems stable for others. Hbm2java tool seems to be buggy.

Comment: I really don't have any idea :). Better post this as a bug.